# Fan is not running in Zorin OS. What do I need to do?

Tags: linux, fan, zorin

Laptop model: HP Pavilion G6 2230TX

Operating System: Zorin 12

Fan runs but can be known only if I place my ears near it. I am even getting error 90b "fan is not operating correctly" at the start up. There is no dust, as I have cleaned it and put new fan in the past week. How to make it run?

Comment: May be the workload is not so much that it runs fan so quickly.

Comment: No, I can feel the heat. Heat adds up, it (cpu) has even reached 80 degree C, without fan running.